# Magento 2: Adding Products to Top Navigation

Tags: magento2, navigation, programming

We have a client who wishes for the top navigation bar to show the products that each toplevel category contains as the child menu items.

I've done a lot of Googling but haven't been able to find anything relevant.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: I also have that kind of requirement, please try to custom module, some times custom module writing is time saving options.

Comment: I managed to achieve it via a plugin and basically taking over the menu assembly programmatically. Would you like me to post the code?

Comment: use this https://github.com/Programmingatkstark/Magento-2-Category-with-image-widget and edit the files as you wish.

Comment: I don't need the code as I did it myself, my edits were to the TOP menu, e.g. the main horizontal navigation bar.